# Multiple ASP.NET targetframeworks in web.config. Which one is being used?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a large ASP.NET solution.  Inside the solution are multiple ASP.NET projects.  Inside each project, is a web.config file.  A few weeks ago, I tried to upgrade all of the projects from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.7.  I did this by right clicking each project in solution explorer, going to properties, and setting the .NET version on the screen that pops up.  Using this method, I was able to easily change all of the projects in the solution to 4.7 (or so I thought).  A few days later, I looked at the web.config file for one of the projects and saw this (incomplete file):

```
  <system.web>
<httpModules/>
<httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<sessionState REMOVED>
  <providers>REMOVED
  </providers>
</sessionState>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7">
```

From what I can tell, the project I'm running uses 4.7, and ignores the 4.5 targetFramework code.  I can access 4.7 API calls, and rolling the code back to 4.5 using the method shown above disables the 4.7 API calls.  Still, I can't help but worry.

To make things more complex, I have text like this in my packages.config file:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**With all that being said, is my project running in 4.7, 4.5, or some kind of bizarre mix?**

**Is my code safe, or is it going to self destruct in some kind of bizarre edge case?**

Comment: related maybe an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170567/what-do-the-targetframework-settings-mean-in-web-config-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @SCFi close!  It doesn't explain why I can run .net 4.7 code in my projects.  The answers weren't upvoted much on that thread.  I consider it to be incomplete.  Hopefully we can get to the bottom of things on this question.