# Upgrading targetframework in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net

When upgrading .net framework of the web app, we right click the project, and increment the target framework.

However, in web.config, this only changes the compilation targetFramework

```
 <compilation targetFramework="4.8" />
```

It does not change the httpRuntime targetFramework

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

Are we suppose to manually update the httpRuntime targetFramework?

Why does Microsoft want us to compile in one framework and run in another framework.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170567/what-do-the-targetframework-settings-mean-in-web-config-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I understand what they are trying to say in that link, but what is the process to force the app run with latest framework? Just type it manually or is there is a way in Visual Studio

Comment: Yes you type it manually into the section to force it.